# NPC killing, who can I kill without having to break questlines in Dark Souls 3?

Tags: dark-souls-3

I have seen this question

[Killing NPC's in Dark Souls](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/261897/killing-npcs-in-dark-souls)

but my problem is a bit different, I dont usually kill NPCs (I killed atleast 3 of them, morne, and 2 guys in the fire link shrine) then after reading much in google, I found out those two guys in the firelink shrine give quests. I tried searching for a list on who could I kill without having any repurcussions (for example, I did not kill the giant throwing spears at me in the undead settlement, and the onion looking guy). I am asking this because for example, Morne died but I could buy his armors and his hammer and shield are my main weapons, are there any other guys like him?

Comment: Fun fact - the giant is actually shooting arrows. When you visit him he has Gough's Bow leaning against the wall

Comment: @Ben, I killed him for the Hawk ring because I finished the game awhile ago, and he really has a bow!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMPORTANT: This answer only discusses the base game (in which I have 100%) as I didn't come around to play the DLCs yet.

Now you need to understand something essential: Dark Souls would never stop you from killing NPCs, and quests aren't always very clearly cut, nor do you have a way of looking them up in-game. The only real exemption are those with which you can achieve a different ending (aka a different 10-seconds cut-scene after the last boss).

Some of them have interesting weapons/armor/spells as reward, but I'd honestly suggest you to simply play and not take the fun out of it by reading it up on the Internet. Nothing really comes close to the feeling when you actually go through an interesting quest-line without knowing what comes next.

Honestly the biggest downside of killing NPCs is probably that some merchants will force you to pay more.

NPCs you can kill (excluding merchants + Quest relevant):

- > the nice giant in Undead Settlement
- > Ludleth of Courland (the last remaining Lord of Cinder)
- > Emma, High Priestess of Lothric Castle (not suggested, you will see later)
- > Eygon of Carim

However, don't fret if you already killed some of them: you probably already broke a lot of more quests and you can't do them all in one run (anymore) anyway. Also, you will be able to buy the armor of many NPCs after killing them from the Shrine Handmaiden.

Additional Fun-Fact (Spoiler):

> Every one I listed will turn up dead anyway

Comment: wow! So Morne gives quest? he just sits there doing nothing! anyways, I will go through your suggestion, I will not ask anymore, and I'll just play Dark Souls like any other game, thank you!

Comment: @Mr.J I am fairly certain Morne is only mentioned in the Dark Souls Lore. You probably mean Eygon of Carim who wears Morne's Armor (Dark Souls Lore tends to be very complicated)

Comment: I think you are right.